# Can I still target .NET Framework 1.1 in VisualStudio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2003, .net-framework-version

I am working with a project which uses .Net Frame V1.1 runs on VisualStudio 2003,
Now, I want to run my project in VisualStudio 2010?
Can I still target .NET Framework 1.1 in VisualStudio 2010?

Answer (score 10):

Visual Studio 2010 only supports the 2.0, 3.0, 3.5, and 4.0 frameworks as targets.  It does not support 1.1.

Is there any reason why you can't upgrade it to .NET 2.0.  Did you know that .NET 1.1 is no longer officially supported on Server 2008 R2 and so I wouldn't expect it to be officially supported on any newer operating system.

I have read of some hacks to build .NET 1.1 projects for VS2005 and VS2008 - see below.  Realize that if you set this up, then everyone else who works on the project will have to go through the same setup.

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BuildingNET11ProjectsUsingVisualStudio2005.aspx

http://devlicio.us/blogs/ziemowit_skowronski/archive/2008/08/22/working-with-net-1-1-in-visual-studio-2008-and-team-server.aspx

Answer (score 7):

No, .NET Framework 1.1 is not supported by Visual Studio 2010.