# Visual Studio 2010 and .NET Framework 1.1.4.322

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, windows-7, .net-framework-version

Is it possible to use visual studio 2010 and .NET Framework 1.4.322 on Windows 7? When I create a new project I can only choose .NET framework v2.0 or later. Is it possible to use v1.1.4.322 and where can I find it?

Comment: .NET 1.1 was never (So far as I'm aware) supported on Windows 7, and is only supported (in any form) until [August this year](http://support.microsoft.com/lifecycle/search/?sort=pn&alpha=.net+framework).

Comment: Linking to my [What can I do to target API in .NET 1.1 from .NET 4.0 (VS2010) project?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15142836/what-can-i-do-to-target-api-in-net-1-1-from-net-4-0-vs2010-project) Have not yet risked to check the answer since I have already experience of screwing my dev machin by such experiments

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a small chart of the Visual Studio and .NET Framework targeting, and short answer is NO

Source [Microsoft .NET Framework and Visual Studio versions](http://www.perceler.com/articles1.php?art=dotnet1)

[image: VS and .NET Versoins Chart]

Comment: This is helpful reference but I hope it is not the final answer. That would be extremely strange that if it happen to be impossible to interoperate from one .NET process with another

Comment: The .NET 4.5 CLR which is CLR Version 4.0 supports side by side execution. So the problem that you have descibed will not be present anymore http://geekswithblogs.net/sdorman/archive/2008/11/10/clr-4.0-in-process-side-by-side-clr-hosting.aspx