# Check C# code for .NET 1.1 compatibility

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, .net-1.1

I'm writing a C# class library, which will be used in a project that runs on .NET Framework 1.1. However, I'm using Visual Studio Ultimate 2010, which doesn't provide tooling for version 1.1.

Is there a static check that I can perform inside VS2010 to see that the code is 1.1 compatible?

Comment: I very much doubt it.  1.1 is also not officially supported anymore - is there any way you can upgrade to .NET 2.0?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8336817/can-i-still-target-net-framework-1-1-in-visualstudio-2010

Answer (score 3):

The `csc` has the ability to check for syntax compatibility. Use the [`langversion`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f4ckecs0.aspx) flag in some post build step to check for program compatibility with `ISO-1`. I would recommend keeping a separate project for the .NET 1.1 library since the conventions after .NET 2.0 greatly diverge.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. However, the langversion mechanism is somewhat limited since it only checks the syntax of C# but is unable to report if the code references class libraries from incompatible frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem in backward compatibility in .NET Framework if you build your application in .NET 4.0 than you can not except that this version will work in .NET 1.1 Framework.
A lot of functions are new or obsoleted.
I think a good idea is to build the project in differents target vesions.

Check this information:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff602939.aspx

Comment: The original question did not mention this, but VS2010 is not used in compiling the code - only for editing.